# Photoshop dialogues displaying on the screen where the main app window is not

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've found this a bit disruptive. So I have multiple monitors on my screen, and there cases when I move application's main window to screen B. I've noticed that when I continue working, on screen B, the dialogues/modals will still appear on screen A. Is there any way for these dialogues to always appear on top of the main app window? When I'm working late night.. sometimes I forget about this behavior, and it drives me nuts to try to figure out why PS has 'frozen.'

Thanks.

Comment: What OS & Ps version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS typically handles positioning of OS-related windows... i.e. open/save/export/alerts etc.

You can move *panels* or *internal dialog windows* (like Layer Styles) and they'll remain in that new position, but generally *not* the os-related windows.

OS windows always assumes the primary monitor for positioning.

Where your "main window" is positioned is irrelevant. It's the primary monitor that the OS items use.

If you want the OS dialogs to appear on monitor B, then you need to set monitor B as the primary monitor - which probably defeats the purpose. I am aware.

(I use 3 monitors and this has always been the case -- except for a bug in AICC causing all OS dialogs to appear on the right-most monitor regardless of the primary monitor setting)